# Remove duplicates from ArrayList<JsonJavaObject> or how to find out if a similar item already exists in arraylist?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have a ArrayList collection of JsonJavaObject (derived from com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.*). When adding more items I would like to check if a similar JSsonObject already exists in the arraylist. How must I do this?

Alternatively I can think of just filling the arraylist with more JsonJavaObject and before returning the result merge the duplicates.

However when I try this e.g. via

```
TreeSet<JsonJavaObject> uniqueHits = new TreeSet<JsonJavaObject>(JSONObjects);
ArrayList<JsonJavaObject> finalHits = new ArrayList<>(uniqueHits);
```

I get an exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject incompatible with java.lang.Comparable

at

TreeSet uniqueHits = new TreeSet(JSONObjects);

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeSet` needs the class to implement `Comparable` since it wants to sort the elements according to some defined order.
Since this is unnecessary for duplicate elimination you can simply use a `HashSet` i.e.

```
Set<JsonJavaObject> uniqueHits = new HashSet<>(JSONObjects);
List<JsonJavaObject> finalHits = new ArrayList<>(uniqueHits);
```